# How to delete a task document in elasticsearch 8.4?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a completed task by using _reindex, but I cannot find any API to delete it. By the way, the task's cancelable value is true

There is the way I have tried:

1. `/_tasks/{task_id}/_cancel` and the server's response is `resource_not_found_exception`
2. `DELETE /.tasks/task/{task_id}` and the server's response is `no handler found for uri [/.tasks/task/QhAvApgFSt-DfjkaMwr9Tg%3A13928717?pretty=true] and method [DELETE]`

Comment: why do you want to delete it?

Comment: @warkolm As the document write 

Running reindex asynchronouslyedit
If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and returns a task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at _tasks/<task_id>. When you are done with a task, you should delete the task document so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space.

So I think the task needs to be deleted, isn't it?

Comment: does `GET _tasks/{task_id}` return anything?

Comment: @warkolm yes, it returns the task's detail message